# Why did the writer choose future continuous instead of present continuous

Tags: present-continuous, future

> Quick reminder as we go into the weekend that **I'll be closing** the order book for the new design T-shirt at noon on Sunday.

I would like to know if it would have been possible to write "am closing" instead of "will be closing". I think so because present continuous can be used to express the future.
Is it because he wrote"go" (present) and to make the reader understand he was speaking of the future he chose "will be closing".

Would it be possible to write this:
Quick reminder as we **will go** into the weekend that **I'm closing** the order book for the new design T-shirt at noon on Sunday.

Comment: Presumably the point of the clause _as we go into the weekend_ is that the weekend is already starting; I imagine the reminder was given on a Friday. There would have been no reason to mention the weekend if the closing date had been announced earlier in the week.

Comment: would am closing be possible in that case .

Comment: Don't forget the question mark! Yes, it would be possible.

Comment: So will it be a difference in meaning using am closing?, sorry for the question mark

Comment: @user5577 The question mark probably refers to the title in your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - No, I meant _would am closing be possible in that case_ (though the title needs one as well!)

Comment: User5577 - No, there is no difference in meaning. The present continuous can be used to indicate a future plan, as in "I'm flying to New York next week".

Comment: Why did the author choose future continuous ? (question of style)

Comment: Only the writer could answer this. If the writer's choice is documented somewhere then the OP could have researched it. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

The form "*I'll be closing the order book*" emphasizes that this is a future event, as the form " I'm closing the order book f" does not.

Also "*as we will go into the weekend*" seems odd or unnatural to me. I would suggest one of:

> - as the weekend starts
> - as we are starting the weekend
> - as the weekend begins
> - for the coming wqeekend

But the form "we will go" just does not seem to fit this context.

Comment: but as the moment is specified(noon on  sunday) even with present continuous the reader knows that the event will happen in the future .